# ssh connection reset docker (gitlab)

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab

$ ssh -v ce.gitro.net -p 2222

> OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>   debug1: Connecting to ce.gitro.net [175.200.135.69] port 2222.
>   debug1: Connection established.
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /c/Users/dreamboy/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /c/Users/dreamboy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /c/Users/dreamboy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /c/Users/dreamboy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /c/Users/dreamboy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /c/Users/dreamboy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /c/Users/dreamboy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /c/Users/dreamboy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
>   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
>   debug1: Authenticating to ce.gitro.net:2222 as 'dreamboy'
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   Connection closed by 175.200.135.69 port 2222

Comment: Any effort on writing something to explain the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, looking at the log files from sshd in /var/log/gitlab/sshd I could see that I had set the wrong permissions for the key files.

In my case running the following solved the problem:

```
chmod -R 700 /etc/gitlab
```